# How to modify tomcat web.xml location per webapplication

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I've multiple spring boot applications deployed in my tomcat server (as war files). My problem is I want to customize tomcat's default `session-timeout` for some of the webapps (ie. without editing the global `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/web.xml`).

I searched and read tomcat docs. It seems the only way I can achieve that is by creating `/WEB-INF/web.xml` inside my war files that needs different `session-timeout` value. But we don't store app specific `web.xml` configurations in our source base.

So what I want to do is create a directory where I'll store all the webapp specific `web.xml` files and tell tomcat to load the `web.xml` file from there and not from my war's `/WEB-INF/web.xml` location.

Example:

For webapp `A.war`, `B.war` I want to have a directory `$CATALINA_BASE/webxmls` which has two web.xml inside like `A_web.xml` and `B_web.xml`. Tomcat will load these web.xml ignoring war's default `/WEB-INF/web.xml` path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by creating seperate `context.xml` for each webapp. According to tomcat docs `context.xml` has an attribute named `altDDName` which can override the absolute path of that webapp's `web.xml`. According to tomcat [docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html):

> altDDName
> The absolute path to the alternative deployment descriptor
> for this context. This overrides the default deployment descriptor
> located at /WEB-INF/web.xml.

So setting the absolute path of my external `web.xml` in `altDDName` will allow me to externally store all my webapp specific `web.xml`s.

Example:

Suppose I've two apps `A.war` and `B.war`. My tomcat is hosted in localhost. I create two seperate `context.xml`s in `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost/A.xml` & `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost/B.xml` with the following property:

`A.xml`

```
<Context altDDName="$CATALINA_BASE/webxmls/A_web.xml">
</Context>
```

and similarly `B.xml`:

```
<Context altDDName="$CATALINA_BASE/webxmls/B_web.xml">
</Context>
```

Now in `$CATALINA_BASE/webxmls/A_web.xml` I can store my external `web.xml` where I can override webapp specific `session-timeout`:

`A_web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
  version="3.1">

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

</web-app>
```

Similarly create new `B_web.xml` for `B.war`.

I hope there are better solution than this. But it solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the path of web.xml by the following way

```
<Context docBase="****" altDDName="$CATALINA_BASE/webxmls.xml">
```